# What signal will come in?

Tags: rf, filter, bluetooth, antenna

I have a simple setup as shown, I would like to know what kind of RF signal will come in? Since the filter is configured around 2.4GHz, will all ISM (WiFi, Bluetooth, Zigbee, etc.) come in?

[image]

The bandpass filter in question is a [TDK DEA202450BT-1213C1](http://product.tdk.com/en/catalog/datasheets/rf_bpf_dea202450bt-1213c1_en.pdf) that [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DEA202450BT-1213C1/445-3969-1-ND/1955566) shows as having a 100 MHz bandwidth.

Comment: Is the passband of the BP filter 1GHz wide or 100Hz wide?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. What is the bandwidth on the BPF?

Comment: 100MHz, I used this one (http://product.tdk.com/en/catalog/datasheets/rf_bpf_dea202450bt-1213c1_en.pdf)

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DEA202450BT-1213C1/445-3969-1-ND/1955566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filter has a 100 MHz bandwidth and a centre frequency of 2.4 GHz, then any frequency in the range 2.35 GHz to 2.45 GHz can be expected to be received on the amplifier's input. Whether this covers the full consumer band, I doubt because I believe the ISM uses a centre frequency of 2.45 GHz meaning your filter ought to have have a centre frequency of 2.45 GHz to cover the whole band.

Comment: I see, so if it were centered at 2.45GHz with 100MHz bandwidth, then basically all ISM signal would flow in and making it nothing buy noise, is that right?

Comment: @Anthony "buy noise"?

Comment: I think he means that the circuit will receive simultaneously all the ISM signals thereby making the output a convoluted mess (i.e. noise).

Comment: @sherrellbc OK I see. No it won't be noise it'll just be a band limited version of the full electromagnetic spectrum and still perfectly usable by an radio receiver that knows how to demodulate the various signals in those bands. It's a practical way of getting rid of really "loud" out-of-band carriers that can break thru due to their sheer amplitude.